# JSON to model with dynamic numeric property

Tags: c#, json, model

I have a JSON that I receive which has dynamic numeric object names. I´m not sure how to convert this into a model.

I have tried to create a model structure but I did not manage to solve it.

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "data_positions": {
        "695243": { <- this is a dynamic number which can be different for another request
            "id": "695243",
            "name": "Gothenburg",
            "numberOfPos": "59865",
            "partners": {
                "9658265": {
                    "id": "9658265",
                    "partner": {
                        "id": "1",
                        "name": "FirstOne"
                    }
                },
                "2365895": { <- this is a dynamic number which can be different for another request
                    "id": "2365895",
                    "participant": {
                        "id": "2",
                        "name": "SecondOne",
                    }
                },
                "1478563": { <- this is a dynamic number which can be different for another request
                    "id": "1478563",
                    "participant": {
                        "id": "3",
                        "name": "ThirdOne"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the model I have created looks like this:

```
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("data_positions")]
    public DataPositions DataPositions { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("numberOfPos")]
    public int NumberOfPos { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("partners")]
    public Partner[] Partners { get; set; }
}

public class Partner
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("numberOfPos")]
    public int NumberOfPos { get; set; }
}
```

So what I´m unsure of is how to fetch the data from the object `695243` under `data_positions` and `2365895`, `1478563` in `partners`.

The expected result is a model that can fetch the data from the JSON provided above.

Appreciate all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing you can do is just use `Dictionary<,>`, eg. `Dictionary<string, DataPosition>`.

Assuming you made a typo in the model and second class should be named `DataPosition` and ignoring the structure of `DataPositions`, the model would look like this:

```
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("data_positions")]
    public Dictionary<string, DataPosition> DataPositions { get; set; }
}

public class DataPosition
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("numberOfPos")]
    public int NumberOfPos { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("partners")]
    public Dictionary<string, Partner> Partners { get; set; }
}

public class Partner
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("numberOfPos")]
    public int NumberOfPos { get; set; }
}
```

You can just access the entry in the dictionary by key, use `.First()` or iterate through them, depending on the data.

PS. The structure for the `Partner` type does not match the JSON, you might want to fix that.

Comment: it´s working now thanks, but I had to do a middle step between the `Partners dictionary` and the `Partner` to be able to fetch the `Partner data`. Or did I miss anything with your answer?